# the dimensionless constant

Tags: physics, dimensional-analysis

when we do the dimensional analysis for the period of the pendulum
we get:$$ {T =f (L,M,g, θ )}$$
We begin by writing the period as a product of these given quantities that have
dimensions:
$${T = b*L^x*M^y*g^z}~~(θ~ is ~dimensionless) $$ where  b is a dimensionless constant. My question is why do we multiply by the dimensionless constant?

Comment: You're gonna need to do a lot more work here to get people to understand what your question is. But nonetheless, here's some more info: https://bandgap.io/blog/buckingham_pi/

Comment: Because dimensional analysis only tells us how the dimensionfull constants are related. It can not tell us if $T = 2\sqrt{L/g}$ or if $T = 69\sqrt{L/g}$. In general $b = b(\theta)$ a function of the only non-dimensionfull parameter in the problem: initial angle $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with the same reasoning but was not sure.